# Actionscript : Going through .as with a variable

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, text, actionscript, instance

I got a variable

```
var Something = "Text";
```

i want to import Text .as that is placed in abc folder
so what can i do? I tried writing :

```
 import abc.Something;
```

Doesn't work, any help?
Btw the main point again, i want to import Text

Answer (score 1):

What you trying to do will not work. The import statement is for classes. You could define your text string in a static variable and then use this variable in your code. Be aware, this is not good design.

```
package abc{
   public class TextHolder
   {
        public static var something:String = "Text"; 
   }
}
```

in another class:

```
package {
   import abc.TextHolder
   public class Main
   {
       var text:String = TextHolder.something;
   }
}
```

You could also use the include statement. With this statment you can include as files in to your current file

```
include "abc.script.as"
```

The variable in this script will then be included in the current script.

What you really want, I guess is to load text and other resources at runtime.

You can simply do that with the URL Loader. 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html

This example is from the adobe livedocs

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;

public class URLLoaderExample extends Sprite {

    private loader:URLoader;
    public function URLLoaderExample() {
        loader = new URLLoader();
        configureListeners(loader);

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("urlLoaderExample.txt");
        try {
            loader.load(request);
        } catch (error:Error) {
            trace("Unable to load requested document.");
        }
    }

    private function configureListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void {
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
    }

    private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
        var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
        trace("completeHandler: " + loader.data);

        var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(loader.data);
        trace("The answer is " + vars.answer);
    }

    private function openHandler(event:Event):void {
        trace("openHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
        trace("progressHandler loaded:" + event.bytesLoaded + " total: " + event.bytesTotal);
    }

    private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
        trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
        trace("httpStatusHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
    }
}
```

}

Its a little bit to much but covers the whole process of loading ascii data.

Comment: I just needed the text of the variable to import as .as
I know it's a bit confusing :S

Comment: You'r very nice for that explanation, but i don't think u get it :P can we talk somewhere? cuz lol it's hard even to explain

Comment: very limited time right now. Sorry. Try to rephrase your question. Is it about text import loading? Or .as file referencing before compiling

Comment: No, i just want to import the value of my string
i mean if my variable abc has the value "asdf"
I want to import asdf... so how can i do it?
OR just to load a function/variable inside asdf